# How does GraphicsPath.Flatten() affects to the drawing performance?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm afraid that I'm experiencing a bug in Winforms/GDI+. I'm building a graphics path composed by a line and then a curve. At some zoom levels (applying a transform matrix to the graphics object) the path is wrongly drawn, see the picture:

[image]

Doing some testing I noticed that if I apply `Flatten()` to the graphics path, the problem dissapears. It seems that the curves are converted to connected segments, and the problem dissapears (this is the code):

```
result.AddLine(sourcex, sourcey, sourcex, sourcey + sourceOffset);
result.AddArc(ellipseContainer, startAngle, sweepAngle);
result.Flatten(); // this line solves the issue!!
```

I have debugged the application and the number of points in the graphics path is 9 without apply `Flatten()`, and 53 applying `Flatten()`.

My question is. What do you think about drawing performance applying Flatten() to graphicsPaths? Do you think that could be affected by this change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could very well be that you're running into a problem of precision at high magnification.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the line to be joined, you should draw it as a polyline using `AddLines`

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Create the line and the curve and then add all the points to the path using AddLines? Could you provide a code sample, please?